# Integration Test with TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, integration-testing, typeorm

I'm doing an integration test by making requests to my dev server by `Supertest`. But I have trouble with how to put data into the database. For example, before run GET test, I want to insert data to the database. But I even can't get a connection from TypeORM:

```
ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.
```

If I even get the connection from TypeORM, how I wrap a test within transaction and rollback transaction after finish the test to make sure the integration test doesn't effect to a real database.

Basically, Is there any package that similar with `factory_bot` of Rails ?

```js
describe("Templates", (): void => {
  describe("GET /api/v1/templates/{templateHash}", (): void => {
    let template: Template;
    beforeEach(
      async (): Promise<void> => {
        let templateService: TemplateService = new TemplateService();
        let connection: Connection = getConnection("default");
        template = new Template(Buffer.from(faker.random.words()), faker.random.uuid(), faker.system.fileName());
        await templateService.create(connection, template);
      },
    );
    it("should return a template", (done): void => {
      request(config.devEnvEndpoint)
        .get(`api/v1/templates/${template.templateHash}`)
        .set("Accept", "application/json")
        .expect(200)
        .end((err, response): void => {
          console.log(response);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like typeorm is not picking up your config. I recommend using the [ormconfig.json](https://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig/using-ormconfigjson) file and have two database configs - one for your development and one for testing.

By having two databases, you won't need to worry about transactions and can drop the database between tests. I suppose transactions would be faster but it really depends on your usecase (I noticed tests were much slower when making lots of `connection.synchronize()` calls).

Then you could use an environment variable to determine which connection to instantiate:

```js
// db.ts
import { Connection, createConnection } from 'typeorm'

let connection: Connection | null = null

export async function getConnection() {
  if (connection) {
    return connection;
  }

  // DATABASE_CONFIG can be 'development' or 'test'
  // and should correspond to the connection names
  // in the ormconfig.json file
  connection = await createConnection(process.env.DATABASE_CONFIG);

  return connection;
}

export async function closeConnection() {
  await connection?.close();
}
```

Then you can set the environment variable and run your tests:

```js
// DATABASE_CONFIG=test yarn test
import { getConnection, closeConnection } from './db'

let connection: Connection;

beforeAll(async () => {
  connection = await getConnection();
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  // Drop everything and recreate db
  await connection.synchronize(true);
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await closeConnection();
});

it('should create a connection', () => {
  expect(connection).toBeDefined();
})
```